# How can I simplify 2 for loops to get a dict object value?

Tags: python

Would there be a way to make the two loops simpler, faster, and cleaner, such as List Comprehension,o(n),etc.

```
def main:
  a={"res":
       [
        {"group":1,"ins":[{"name":"aa","id":123]},
        {"group":2,"ins":[{"name":"cc","id":456]}
     ]}
   result=[]
  for key in a["res"]:
     for i in key["ins"]
        result.append(i)
  return result
```

Comment: Are you primarily trying to make the code more Pythonic or make it run faster?  Also, typo: `"re"` or `"res"`.

Comment: I want to make it faster and cleaner. @jarmod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = [i for key in a['res'] for i in key['ins']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

# 3.21 µs ± 23.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)    
np.ravel([z["ins"] for z in a["res"]]).tolist()
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'aa', 'id': 123}, {'name': 'cc', 'id': 456}]
```

Edit:

You could also try a faster option:

```
# 372 ns ± 11.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
sum([z["ins"] for z in a["res"]],[])
```

Comment: Would be interesting to add the load/import time of numpy into this timing.

Comment: Oh good point, the first option does not consider the import for the timing so both are comparable